# Gulp mocha istanbul get 100% for nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js, istanbul

I use the following code and It was able to generate the mocha test (suite and tests) report as **expected** but Im not able to see the ***mocha test coverage with istanbul*** what am I missing here?

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    gulp.src(['./assets/**/js/*.js'])//Here I took it from the repo
        .pipe(istanbul())
        .pipe(tap(function (f) {
            require(f.path);
        }))
        .on('end', function () {
            gulp.src(['test/*spec.js'])//this is the path for my tests
                .pipe(mocha({
                    reporter: 'mochawesome'
                }))
                .pipe(istanbul.writeReports(
                    ['unit-test-coverage']
                ));
        });
});
```

the following does not generate anything

```
  .pipe(istanbul.writeReports(
                ['unit-test-coverage']
            ));
```

My project look like following

```
my app
 -server.js
 -app.js
 -contoller
 --file1.js
 --file2.js
 -test
  spec1.js
  spec2.js
 -gulpfile.js
```

1. what should I put here?
   gulp.src(['./assets/**/js/*.js']) ?
2. how should I adopt my code to make it work?

I use the following
https://github.com/SBoudrias/gulp-istanbul
and gulp mocha
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mocha

**And this is what I got after the code are running**

19 passing (15s)

```
[mochawesome] Report saved to mochawesome-reports/mochawesome.html


----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|


=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 100% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : 100% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
```

**UPDATE**
When I do the following it generate an report but the coverge but it seems that the code is not coverage well since I got 100% on of all the tests (I wish :-)) ,any idea what I miss here?
since the mocha unit test run well just the code coverage doesnt work well

```
            .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({
                dir: './assets/unit-test-coverage',
                reporters: ['html'],
                reportOpts: {dir: './unit-test-coverage'}
            }));
```

**update 2**

I build the same in  **GRUNT**  (since I was lost here :-( ) and this is working!!!!!

but still I want to make it work in Gulp, please help!

I try to sperate all the dependcies and create this minor gulp file and run 
just it and still the same issue

This is the new file and I use diffrent technuiqe but same results :(

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');


gulp.task('pre-test', function () {

    return gulp.src(['./assets/**/js/*.js'])
    // Covering files

        .pipe(istanbul(
            {includeUntested: true}
        ))
        .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('test', ['pre-test'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['test/*spec.js'])
        .pipe(mocha({
            reporter: 'mochawesome'
        }))
        // Creating the reports after tests ran
        .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({
            dir: './assets/unit-test-coverage',
            reporters: ['html'],
            reportOpts: {dir: './unit-test-coverage'}
        }))
        .pipe(istanbul.enforceThresholds({thresholds: {global: 90}}));
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'test']);
```

WHAT am I missing here? the test file running OK just the coverage...

Comment: It seems you don't have `assets` folder. Atleast "My project look like following" doesn't have it. Try `return gulp.src(['/**/*.js', '!test/', '!gulpfile.js']).pipe(istanbul(...))`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - thanks Yury you give some direction but it seems that when I want to use the root path of my files I should put them explicit way? I use now the following pattern            './*/**.js',
            'app.js',   and as you can see I put the app.js explicit,there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - when I try the pattern you put I got permission error '/**/*.js' so I try this and this is working  './*/**.js', 'app.js' ... you can add your replay as answer...Thanks!

Comment: Sure. You need cwd relative path. I have missed the dot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was in comment.

It seems you don't have `assets` folder. Atleast "My project look like following" doesn't have it. Try

```
return gulp
  // all js files from cwd excluding test folder and gulpfile
  .src(['./**/*.js', '!test/', '!gulpfile.js'])
  .pipe(istanbul(...))
```

Comment: Thank a lot ,I've additional question please see if you can assist please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583304/gulp-load-plugins-error-dep-is-not-defiend