# Gulp load plugins error dep is not defiend

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-load-plugins

I try to use gulp-load-plugins but I got error .

for example I try the following

```
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});


    gulp.task('run', function () {
        return gulp.src(config.files)
            .pipe($.istanbul(
                {
                    instrumenter: isparta.Instrumenter
                }
            ))
            .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire());
    });
```

when I remove the var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul'); I got error
 **ReferenceError: istanbul is not defined**

```
   "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-istanbul": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "istanbul": "0.4.4",
    "mocha": "2.2.5",
    ...
}
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$.istanbul`

```
.pipe($.istanbul.hookRequire())
```

Comment: Thanks now its working but for mocha not  .pipe($.mocha({ , here I got error <b>$.mocha is not a function </b>

Comment: @JennyM. You need to install `gulp-mocha`. `gulp-load-plugins` resolves plugins by name `gulp-blah` becomes `$.blah`